# Different checks for the same action?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, difficulty-class

Situation: Players are investigating a field trying to find a missing dog.

Would it be reasonable to allow a DC 15 investigation or a DC 12 survival to get the "same" information of "dog goes west".

The reasoning would be that someone who is good at tracking would know what they were looking for, resulting in a lower DC.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about making a row/sequence of different checks or are you asking about a single check?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is very common at most tables and is used in many official adventure modules. A situation can often be resolved with an easier check using the most appropriate skill, or a harder check using a less-appropriate skill to get the same information. There may even be *several* more- and less-appropriate options available, depending on the situation. (I would only come up with a single DC for each category, though. Trying to rank three or four skills and give them all different DCs sounds like too much work for no real benefit.)

Often, modules (or DMs) will present *similar* information but with a slightly different slant based on the skill used. For example, History might give you stories about the people who used to own a ruined keep, while Investigation might turn up clues to what kind of people they were without having family names and such: more specific details, less names and context.

In the situation you described, I'd be inclined to have a Survival check allow the PCs to actually follow the dog's trail, where Investigation says "It left the field going west" but doesn't allow you to track the animal, which is a specific use of Survival. But knowing a general direction is enough to maybe ask around or search for clues further on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could have multiple checks, using different skills and having different DC's.  As a DM, you could allow different PC's to independently come up with the same basic information. Although, different skills might return different information, or allow follow up actions.

You might get similar pieces of information using different checks, assuming as a DM they are relevant.  Like your Investigation vs Survival checks...  You might be able to answer that the dog went Westward using either of them.  However, using Survival, you might be able to Track the dog's footprints/trail signs and follow them until you no longer can (either DC wise or story wise) ... while Investigation, might point you to another location in a general sense, where you could Investigate again.
Or if you did both, maybe you could Investigate where Tracking started to fail.

As pointed out, depending on the skill used, you might get information that is skill slanted. e.g. One skill's might be more depth based, vs another that's more broadly answered.  The DM will determine what exactly you find out.

Sometimes, answers are listed as a series of linked DC's e.g. Very common information might be DC 5 or 10, uncommon might be DC 15,  rare might be DC 20, etc.
And players might be able to learn pieces of info that way that's relevant to the story.

Answer (score 1):

### There are no "investigation" or "survival" checks in D&D 5e - there are only [ability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityChecks) checks

While we all sometimes think of skill checks, that's not in the rules.

So, for your example, the correct way to think of it is to set a DC15 Intelligence check (to which a character proficient in Investigation would apply their proficiency bonus) and a DC12 Wisdom check (ditto except for Survival).

Alternatively, you can decide that tracking a dog uses Intelligence (Mental acuity, information recall, analytical skill) rather than Wisdom (Awareness, intuition, insight) [or vice-versa] and set a single DC and use the variant rule allowing Skills to be applied to any ability check. So, if you decided it's a DC12 Intelligence check and that Survival or Investigation will allow the proficiency bonus to apply.

Or, you could allow either ability to apply (like resisting a grapple can use Strength or Dexterity) and set the same or different DCs for either Intelligence or Wisdom. Again you can use or not use the variant rule.

I strongly recommend using the variant rule. It allows you to set DCs much more straightforwardly by focusing on only 6 ability scores and allowing the players to decide how to approach the solution. Remember, they describe what they want to do - is what they are describing an application of Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma? Do they have skills that are applicable to their solution?

For your which way did the dog go problem, it's hard to see an approach that won't be based on Intelligence or Wisdom. Is there a reason why one ability would be better than another?

### However, don't change the DC to cater for the person's skill

> The reasoning would be that someone who is good at tracking would know what they were looking for, resulting in a lower DC.

No! The natural talent (ability score) and skill (proficiency) of the person doesn't change the inherent difficulty of the task. The tracks are just as hard to find and interpret no matter who's doing the looking - just like an exam paper is just as hard whether or not the student is good at maths.

The person with the appropriate skill and a high ability score is already being rewarded because they have a better chance of success, Lowering the DC is rewarding them twice.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, although a variance of 3 isn't ideal.

Typically the difference between a 'good' skill and a 'poor' skill for the average D&D 5e character that I have seen in actual play (not example characters or npcs) is 5 or more.  Key attributes are *rarely* lower than 16, and proficiencies are few.  For the typical level of play (1-6) this means you're looking at a range of -1 to +6, for a typical character.  Expertise, Guidance, and the Help action all vastly improve prospects in this regard, with Advantage (usually from Help, Inspiration, or situation) helping the most.

Therefore it can be a good idea to have a DC gap of 5 or so to differentiate skills that are best suited to solving problems from others.  It really helps mathematically if it's significantly harder to use non suited skills, as it is one of the few reasons not to simply take the biggest numbers in combat attribute + constitution as you can, with the other major one being saving throws.

Effectively, it should be a reasonable choice to try for Survival instead of Investigation in your example even if you are better at Investigation.  A 3 point gap means it's likely the wizard shouldn't look for tracks even if they haven't dumped wisdom and don't have proficiency in investigation, they should try to investigate, simply due to higher int.  A 5 point gap means they should trudge around looking for tracks more often than simply trying to Sherlock literally any problem you will allow them to roll their sherlocking (or arcana, or what have you) for.

The usual other things apply to skill checks as well -

-the results of a skill check should be related to solving the problem, but also related to the type of skill check it is (Arcana should solve a problem in a different way to History - with potentially different side effects or other outcomes, decoding the runes directly and alerting the Lich as its ward is dispelled rather than finding the servants corridor that allows you to go unremarked albeit taking longer to 'go around')

-skill checks should result in tiered success at least some of the time - 10 on a History check giving you some vague facts, 15 giving a name, 20 giving that there might be a way into the city, 25 giving you the link between the von Eriovs and the ancient dragon known as Red-Heart.  Which applies even if multiple skills can be used, so you might need to differentiate and tier the results of skill checks (either in play or during prep).

-if someone is especially good at a specific skill check or it is intimately tied to their character in some way, they should be able to succeed at certain kinds of skill checks without needing to roll (a hunter from the mountains recognizing wolf tracks while in the mountains, for example)